# semantic-ui extend existing css classes

Tags: semantic-ui, bourbon, neat

I've kind of comparing Bourbon Neat and Semantic-UI - if I don't really have access to the html code it is simple in Neat to apply grid classes to existing HTML code/elements and set up the overall layout/structure of a page with content and sidebar - how would I do that using Semantic UI.

Comment: Please be more specific on what you're trying to achieve. Generally, Semantic UI won't help you much if you can't modify the HTML.

Comment: I've an WP template/framework that uses some classes for the structure of the page like main content, sidebar 1, sidebar 2, header columns and footer columns - using neat, it is easy to apply unobtrusive code to those elements like e.g. .main-content { @include span-columns(8) } - does Semantic UI offer something like this - moreover, I've read somewhere that flex-boxes should not be used for the main layout so that might be an issue with Semantic UI anyway